# Await method that returns Task - spins forever?

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

I have the following NUnit test class:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    async Task<string> GetMessageAsync()
    {
        return "Hello from GetMessageAsync!";
    }

    Task<string> GetMessageTask()
    {
        return new Task<string>(() => "Hello from GetMessageTask!");
    }

    [Test]
    public async void AwaitAsyncMethod()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("Hello from GetMessageAsync!", await GetMessageAsync());
    }

    [Test]
    public async void AwaitTaskMethod()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("Hello from GetMessageTask!", await GetMessageTask());
    }
}
```

The first test, AwaitAsyncMethod(), completes successfully immediately upon execution.  The second test, AwaitTaskMethod(), never completes.  But it does compile.

Why does the second test never complete?  Why can I compile an await against a non-async method, if seemingly it doesn't actually work?  Let's say for some reason I want a non-async method to return a task that can be awaited - how do I change this code to accomplish that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new Task(...)` returns an unstarted `Task`.
Until you call `Start()`, that task will never finish, and anything waiting for it will never run.

Instead, you can call `Task.Run()`, which will create and start a task for you.

Comment: Aha.  Task.Run is what I was missing.  Thanks.