# Func doesn't work & blocked during test execution

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, nunit, .net-6.0

**Prerequisites:**

1. .NET 6.0
2. C# 10
3. NUnit 3.13.3

**Context:**
Try to run an unit test, but run into some kind of thread blocker. The code just stop execution on

```
value = await getDataToCacheAsync.Invoke();
```

The last row that can be debugged is

```
return () => new Task<string?>(() => cacheValue [there]);
```

**Q:** It looks like there is some kind of deadlock happened, but it's not clear for me why and how it can be addressed

**Unit test:**

```
[Test]
public async Task GetCachedValueAsync_WithDedicatedCacheKey_ReturnsExpectedCacheValue()
{
    const string cacheKey = "test-cache-key";
    const string cacheValue = "test-cache-key";

    var result = await _sut.GetCachedValueAsync(cacheKey, GetDataToCacheAsync(cacheValue));

    Assert.AreEqual(cacheValue, result);
}

private static Func<Task<string?>> GetDataToCacheAsync(string cacheValue)
{
    return () => new Task<string?>(() => cacheValue);
}
```

**The code under test:**

```
public async Task<T?> GetCachedValueAsync<T>(string cacheKey, Func<Task<T?>> getDataToCacheAsync)
                where T : class
{

    // [Bloked here, nothing happens then, I'm expecting that it should return "test-cache-value"]

    value = await getDataToCacheAsync.Invoke(); [Blocked]
                ...
    return value
}
```

Comment: Related: [Awaiting an empty Task spins forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298313/awaiting-an-empty-task-spins-forever-await-new-task)

Answer (score 2):

After

`return () => new Task<string?>(() => cacheValue [there]);`

was replaces with

```
return () => Task.FromResult(cacheValue);
```

it started work

**UPD:**

It seems like the root cause is that a task should be started directly before awaiting it, in such cases (e.g. Task.Run(...), TaskFactory ... etc.).

Task.FromResult returns already completed task with a result

Comment: Your answer would be even better when you tell why this works and the previous way did not.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's steal not clear for me :)

Comment: It seems like the root cause is that the task should be start directly in such cases (e.g. Task.Run(...)).

Comment: Task.FromResult returns already completed task with a result

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-task-ctor(system-action)) generally you should try to avoid creating tasks via constructor:

> This constructor should only be used in advanced scenarios where it is required that the creation and starting of the task is separated.
>
> Rather than calling this constructor, the most common way to instantiate a `Task` object and launch a task is by calling the static `Task.Run(Action)` or `TaskFactory.StartNew(Action)` method.

The issue being that task created by constructor is a "cold" one (and according to [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap?redirectedfrom=MSDN#task-status) you should avoid returning "cold" tasks from methods, only "hot" ones) - it is not started so `await` will result in endless wait (actually no deadlock happening here).

There are multiple ways to fix this code, for example:

1. Use `Task.Run`:

```
return () => Task.Run(() => cacheValue);
```

2. Start created task manually (though in this case there is no reason to. Also as noted by [@Theodor Zoulias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11178549/theodor-zoulias) - [it is recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2008) to specify explicitly the scheduler when calling the `Start` method. Otherwise the task will be scheduled on the ambient `TaskScheduler.Current`, which can be a source of some issues):

```
return () => 
{ 
    var task = new Task<string?>(() => cacheValue); 
    task.Start(); 
    return task;
}
```

3. Return a completed task (which I think is the best way in this case, unless you are testing a very specific scenario):

```
return () => Task.FromResult(cacheValue);
```

Comment: +1. Regarding the second solution, [it is recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2008 "CA2008: Do not create tasks without passing a TaskScheduler") to specify explicitly the `scheduler` when calling the [`Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.start) method. Otherwise the task will be scheduled on the ambient `TaskScheduler.Current`, which might not be what you want or expect.